# Voting is Moderation, and we need more Moderation

Tags: discussion, voting

As discussed by [Grace Note](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/10/welcome-valued-associate-chris-jaeger/) we [need more moderation](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/hands-on-moderation-is-essential-for-this-community-to-continue) if this site is to continue.  The easiest form of moderating is to vote.

So far, 28 days into this month, we only have [17 users](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=month) with more than 10 votes, and only 5 with more than 20 votes.

So I want to ask three related (semi-rhetorical) questions:

1. Is there any point in voting?
2. If nobody is voting, doesn't that mean the Data Science is Broken?
3. How can we change the situation?

Answer (score 12):

#### Why Bother?

1. Well for starters, it is not much a bother, since it is trivially easy.

   If you have taken the time to stop by meta to read this, I imagine that you took a look at the questions on the main site first.  Did you vote on any of those that you read?
2. Because we need more high reputation users.

   As of today we don't have a single 10k user and we only have 9 users with a enough reputation to go to the close/reopen queues with the standard 3k reputation level.
3. Votes are signposts for those that come after you.

   So voting is good karma.  It helps to communicate your experience and knowledge to others.  Even if it is just a tiny a bit at a time.

#### Why doesn't anybody vote, is [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) Broken?

I do not think the site is broken, as other sites have faced the same challenge.  A quick search finds many similar meta posts.  So [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) is traveling a familiar path.

[4/10](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217/are-you-voting), [3/11](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/are-people-voting-enough), [4/12](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/894/why-arent-we-voting-more), [3/13](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/community-outreach-be-more-liberal-with-voting), [8/13](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/how-can-we-encourage-more-voting), [1/14](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/611/how-do-we-get-people-to-vote-more), [1/14](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321/why-are-so-few-votes-on-chemistry-stackexchange), [2/14](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/vote-vote-vote-vote-vote-vote-vote), [8/14](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/lets-try-to-do-some-more-up-voting), [10/14](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/why-arent-people-voting-how-can-we-get-people-to-get-more-engaged), [8/15](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/812/is-there-a-way-to-encourage-voting), [9/17](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/why-doesnt-anyone-vote-on-this-site)

#### How can we change the situation?

Well, *you* can vote.  Consider this a plea to spend a bit of your time voting whenever *you* stop by.

Besides, who wouldn't want to [earn](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/6/supporter) a [nice](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/suffrage) [shiny](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi) [badge](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) or [two](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate)?

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the effort to write this great answer :)  Completely agree with this!

Comment: don't you need only a reputation of 500 to cast close votes?

Comment: @oW_ For the 4 graduated sites on which I have review privileges, it is 3000 for close/reopen, 2000 for edits/quality and 500 for first/late.  I don't know if or when this site will make the change.